# Song in My Hero Academia season 1 episode 10, at around 10:50

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

There's a song in *My Hero Academia* that plays in:

- season 1 episode 10 at around 10:50
- season 2 episode 3 when showing everyone on the minefield
- season 3 episode 7 showing all the students and teachers walking back to camp after the villains left.

What is that song?

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE. I'd like to just make sure that all of these are the same song, right? Because if you ask about multiple different songs, then each should be posted as a separate question instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**[The Threat of Offense and Defense (脅威との攻防 Kyōi to no kōbō)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bp8MHZFC6JU&t=2981s)**

I haven't seen episode 7 of season 3 yet, but assuming it's the same song as the first two, there you go :)