# A song in Boku no Hero Academia season 3 episode 45 at 9:50

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

There's a song played for a short amount of time in *Boku no Hero Academia* season 3 episode 45 at 9:50. I think this song hasn't been played before in the series.

What is that song?

Answer (score 2):

**[The Threat of Offense and Defense (脅威との攻防 Kyōi to no kōbō)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bp8MHZFC6JU&t=2981s)**

[As another user pointed out](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/47097/song-in-my-hero-academia-season-1-episode-10-at-around-1050/47112#47112), it has actually been played at least twice before!

- season 1 episode 10 at around 10:50
- season 2 episode 3 when showing everyone on the minefield

Answer (score 0):

It is "Kyōi to no kōbō" (The Threat of Offence and Defense), the 29th track from *Boku No Hero Academia Original Soundtrack*. ([YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwtMpGBBq9I&list=PLBGT0Gf50F_dzpSQpXEJVZePI6je32jZj&index=28))